# How to set elemnts of numpy array based on elements of another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to set elemnts of array1 to nan based on elements of array2 which are nan.

The following is my code (which isn't working)

I would greatly appreciate assistance :)

```
array1 = np.array([1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.])
array2 = np.array([2.,2.,2.,2.,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2.,2.,2.])

#I want to create:
#[1.,1.,1.,1.,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1.,1.,1.]

# I've tried:
array1[array2 == np.nan] = np.nan
print(array1)
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argwhere` to find the indices with `np.nan` and finally use those indices to change the value of array1.

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.])
array2 = np.array([2.,2.,2.,2.,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2.,2.,2.])

inds = np.argwhere(np.isnan(array2))
print(inds)
array1[inds] = np.nan

print(array1)
```

```
[[4]
 [5]
 [6]]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan nan  1.  1.  1.]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use np.isnan.

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.])
array2 = np.array([2.,2.,2.,2.,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2.,2.,2.])
array1[np.isnan(array2)] = np.nan
print(array1)
```

Output is as desired:

```
[ 1.  1.  1.  1. nan nan nan  1.  1.  1.]
```